# Python TypeError ("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'") whenever an import is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a strange bug that started happening recently. Whenever I attempt to import a module that does not exist, I get a `TypeError` instead of an `ImportError`:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 30 2017, 10:05:52)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import missing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 946, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 885, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1157, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1129, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1268, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 60, in _path_join
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 60, in <listcomp>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

This seems to be a "you tried to call a python2 lib from python3, silly" type error, but it clearly has nothing to do with code that I wrote (as you can see by the above traceback -- I just start a repl, `import missing`, and the error happens). This behavior started happening shortly after I installed python 3.6, but it also happens in my python3.5 REPL (which I kept around), so it's probably not related to that.

Any guesses as to what might be going on? I poked around in importlib a bit, but I'm pretty much just at a loss here.

EDIT: Mystery solved, see comment.

Comment: This happens on any import that is not present, right?  There isn't some crazy conflict where you actually have a package called `missing`, right?

Comment: huh, what are the Python versions? I can't recreate this with `3.5.3rc1+`, `3.6.0+` or `3.7.0a0`.

Comment: @BlackVegetable correct; the same thing happens with arbitrary garbage import names.

Comment: Could you output your `pwd` and python path?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard `python --version` says `Python 3.6.0`. Clearly, something funky is going on here. For reference, I'm using a mac, and installed python 3.6 via pyenv, but the same error also occurs on python3.5 installed via homebrew. I'm sure my system configuration has something to do with it, but I don't even know where to start looking.

Comment: @BlackVegetable -- good suggestion! I have now solved the mystery. Here's what was going on: my pwd was a git repository, and I have startup.py hook that detects git repositories and ensures that the repo root is on the sys path when I'm in a REPL. It was putting a bytes object (not a string) on sys.path, causing this error.

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved: the problem was in a ~/.config/startup.py function that was putting the git repository root onto the system path (such that whenever your cwd is in a git repository, you can start up a REPL and import modules defined in that repository). This was inserting the result of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` onto the sys path, and this is a bytes object in python 3, which causes `importlib` to complain.

Comment: This was the line of source code inspection that led me to suspect something funky that led to this answer: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#l60